# Is it always necessary to create a class for calculate table in C#?

Tags: c#, class, oop

I have a calculate table:

| RowsName | Parameter1 | Parameter2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 20 | 5 |
| Name2 | 4 | 6 |
| … |  |  |
| Sum | 100 | 100 |

Is it necessary to create a class for the table? It seems to me, that in this case it is just complicates the program, and it is not necessary.

But I have tried to create a class:

```
public class Table
{
        public string RowsName { get; set; }
        public double Parameter1 { get; set; }
        public double Parameter2 { get; set; }
        public static int RowNumber=15;
}
```

Then I tried to use it :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Table[] row = new Table[Table.RowNumber];

        for (int i = 0; i < Table.RowNumber; i++)
        {
            row[i] = new Table();                
            row[i].Parameter1  = IOData.valueParameter1 [i];
            row[i].Parameter2  = IOData.valueParameter2[i];
        }

        row[Table.RowNumber-1].Parameter1  = IOData.valueParameter1 .Sum();
        row[Table.RowNumber-1].Parameter1  = IOData.valueParameter2 .Sum();
  }
```

And I have a method of parameters output :

```
   public static void DataOutput(string[] rowsName, params double[][] column)
   {           
        for (int i = 0; i <column[0].Length; i++)
        {                
            Console.Write("{0,12:0.00}|",rowsName[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < column.Length; j++)
                Console.Write("{0,12:0.00}|", column[j][i]);

            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }
```

But I can't call this method with arrays of properties of my object. How can I do something like this?

```
DataOutput(row[].Parameter1, row[].Parameter2);//this is does not work
```

And I need to create two additional arrays :

```
double[] outputParameter1 = new double[Table.RowNumber];
double[] outputParameter2= new double[Table.RowNumber];

for (int i = 0; i < Table.RowNumber; i++)
{
    outputParameter1[i] = row[i].Parameter1;
    outputParameter2[i] = row[i].Parameter2;
}            

IOData.DataOutput( outputParameter1 , outputParameter2);
```

I think it will be much simpler if I didn't create a class, just two arrays, and work with them. But I want to write code, as if it was written by experienced developer. So my question is:

Comment: _"So my question is:..."_ - you are leaving us in suspence ;)

Comment: Class is not necessary it just simplifies things. It creates OOP features.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using LINQ, something like this:

```
var column1 = row.Select(r => r.Parameter1).ToArray();
var column2 = row.Select(r => r.Parameter2).ToArray();

DataOutput(column1, column2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("RowsName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Parameter1", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Parameter2", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Name1", 20, 5 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Name2", 4, 6 });

            var sums = Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Columns.Count).Select(x => (x == 0) ? (object)"Sum" : (object)dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(y => y.Field<int>(x))).ToArray();
            
            DataRow row = dt.Rows.Add();
            row.ItemArray = sums;
        }
    }
}
```